# DataTable normalize blanks cells

Tags: c#, excel, datatable

I have not found a method to normalize a DataTable that came from an Excel with merged cells. When I get the DataTable from that Excel, only the first cell has the value, others are blank.

An example of this DataTable is:

[image]

and the expected result:

[image]

To summarize: blanks cells should be completed with the value of the next cell above with a value, since is what was happened with the Excel merge of cells.

I'm using Excel.dll to read this Excel, didn't provide the autofill of cells, so that's why I'm searching for a method inside C#.

I suppose that logic should be: if a cell is blank, use the upper cell as a value. The logic appears clear but I have issues trying to get the code to apply it.

This is a sample, but at the end, I'm looking for a method to do this whenever columns or rows have the datatable.

**Edit**:
Thanks for your quicky feedback.
Attached what i have so far for just only one column and with errors since doesn't take care of the first and last row, but is the idea... what i try to achieve is to have a method for any amount of cols and rows (could be ok if cols are fixed with names, and then if i have more columns i will adapt).

```
        private void NormalizeDataTable(DataTable dtRawTable)
    {

        DataTable dtFinalized = new DataTable();
        dtFinalized.Columns.Add("Col1", typeof(String));

        string previousValue = "";

        for (int index = 0; index <= dtRawTable.Rows.Count; index++)
        {
            DataRow dr = dtFinalized.NewRow();



            if (index != 0 || index == dtRawTable.Rows.Count -1)
            {

                if (dtRawTable.Rows[index]["Modelo"].ToString() == "")
                {
                    dr["Col1"] = previousValue;
                }
                else
                {
                    dr["Col1"] = Convert.ToString(dtRawTable.Rows[index]["Modelo"].ToString());
                    previousValue = (string)dr["Col1"];
                }
            }

            dtFinalized.Rows.Add(dr);
            dtFinalized.AcceptChanges();


        }
    }
```

Comment: this will be very difficult to see why this is happening without seeing your code.. this could be a number of reasons can you post your code that relates to what you have

Comment: Reading the sheet row by row would help... simply copiying the last row and replacing the cellvalues if they are not empty... however, as a finished table you may loop each row... without any information what you are going to to with it, makes it hard to help...

Answer (score 0):

Here is the function i using in my project for same requirement.

```
public static DataTable AutoFillBlankCellOfTable(DataTable outputTable)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < outputTable.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < outputTable.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    if (outputTable.Rows[i][j] == DBNull.Value)
                    {
                        if (i > 0)
                            outputTable.Rows[i][j] = outputTable.Rows[i - 1][j];
                    }
                }
            }
            return outputTable;
        }
```